# WINAPI C++ VS 2008 vs VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I've been writing an application that monitors certain directory for files being added, and sending those files in certain order. It does work perfectly. But I've encountered an interesting problem - I wrote this project on Windows XP, using VS 2008, and I need to merge my solution with another one, located on PC with Windows 7 and VS 2010, but the code I wrote just simply doesn't work the same! A. k. a. I've treated TCHAR* as char*, as far as I know it shouldn't give problems, but on VS 2010 the conversion doesn't happen. The code is posted below.

```
int ftp_send(char* filename, TCHAR* path) {     
FILE *fPtr,*fp;     
char s[128],*loc=NULL;
char command1[1024];
char log[1024];
char systemcom[2048];
char name1[1024];
int success = 0;

sprintf_s(command1, 1024, "open 127.0.0.1\nbear\nitriv100\nbinary\nprompt\nmput %s\\rev%s*\n\nbye\n", path, filename);
sprintf_s(log, 1024, "%s\\log.txt", path);
sprintf_s(name1, 1024, "%s\\ftp.txt", path);
sprintf_s(systemcom, 2048, "ftp -s:%s -d | find\"226\"  >  %s", name1, log);
//printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", systemcom, name1, log);
fopen_s(&fp, name1, "w+"); 
fprintf(fp,command1);

fclose(fp);

while(!success){
    system(systemcom);
    fopen_s(&fPtr, log, "r");
    if (!fPtr) {         
        printf("open file failure...\n");         
        return -1;     
    }          
    while (fgets(s, 128, fPtr) != NULL) { 
        loc = strstr(s, "226");
        if(loc != NULL) {     
            printf("File rev%s completely!!\n",filename);
            success = 1;
            return 0; 
        }
    }   
fclose(fPtr);
}
return -1;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Constantine

Comment: please what "doesn't work the same" mean exactly ? any error messages/exceptions ? unexpected behaviour ?

Comment: Have you debugged it? Can you point out the exact line where you feel there is a problem?

Comment: "doesn't work the same" I meant that it gives me error in line fprintf(fp, command1); I know that this mistake is caused by invalid string name1, since I didn't check descriptor fp for validity, it tried writing to a file directly.

Comment: What do you mean "the conversion doesn't happen"?  Are you referring to the Visual Studio 2008 Project -> Visual Studio 2010 Project conversion wizard?  If so, are there any error messages in the conversion log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, the problem here is that your VS 2008 project was Multibyte CharacterSet based and VS 2010 project is UNICODE based.

Right-click on **Project->Properties->General->Character Set**

Change it to '**Use Multi-Byte Character Set**'.

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code `UNICODE` based, then add `_T` before all the strings that you are defining.

Answer (score 3):

TCHAR != char and 'TCHAR *' != 'char *'
it's a define for 'char' data type or 'wchar_t' data type depending on macro UNICODE or _UNICODE.

you can use 'TCHAR' instead 'char' in your code, and replace functions like 'sprintf_s' with their TCHAR analog, e.g. '_stprintf_s' defined in <tchar.h>

Answer (score 0):

You've probably defined `UNICODE` somewhere. Check [`Character Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx) in Project Properties. Fixing this should make the code  compile.

You could have avoided this issue by using `TCHAR` and it's related functions correctly, rather than assuming `TCHAR = char`.